# How to parse json data from Dataset using JsonConvert SerializeObject

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, wcf

I am using WCF service to interact data from database to get data and post data. For that using jquery ajax. I am getting data from WCF Service. But I unable to parse json data. I tried most of the ways. But i cant achieve.

**WCF Service:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetUserDetails?uname={uname}",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetUserDetails(string userName);
}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements
(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class Service : IService
{
    public string GetUserDetails(string userName)
    {
        SqlParameter[] sqlparams = new SqlParameter[1];
        DataLayer dal = new DataLayer();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        sqlparams[0] = new SqlParameter("@UserName", userName);

        ds = dal.GetDataSet("dbConn", "GetUserDetailsSP", sqlparams);

        string jsonValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);
        return jsonValue; ;
    }
}
```

**Ajax:**

```
        $.ajax({                 
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: './Services/Service.svc/GetUserDetails',
                data: { uname: 'e0205' },
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    //var testMsg = $.parseJSON(response);
                    alert(response.GetUserDetailsResult);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
```

**Json Data:**

```
{"GetUserDetailsResult":"{\"Table\":[{\"UserName\":\"E0205\",\"EmpName\":\"Manjeet\",\"LocationName\":\"Gurgaon\",\"Designation\":\"Analyst\"}]}"}
```

I am struggling to parse data in ajax here.

Answer (score 0):

since I am not able to see the response what is actually getting returned from the service

I suggest trying:

1) `JSON.parse(response.data);`

and since your `dataType:'json'`

you could simply use

```
...
success: function (response) {
    console.log(response.GetUserDetailsResult.Table[0]);
},
```

Comment: i am tried both ways as you mentioned. am getting error only. any other possible ways there

Comment: run the application on mozilla firefox with firebug...and post what you getting in the console

Comment: Getting **Uncaught TypeError:** Cannot read property 'UserName' of undefined

Comment: did you use `response.GetUserDetailsResult.Table.UserName` in your success function? put `console.write(response);` in your success function `console.write(error)` in your error function and then post the console result

Comment: put `console.write(response);` in your success function `console.write(error);` in your error function and then post the console result.....

Comment: In console am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'UserName' of undefined` only and Json Result too

Comment: so you are getting a proper reponse from the webservice.....remove `response.GetUserDetailsResult.Table.UserName` and put `console.write(response.GetUserBranchPermissionDetailsResult);` this time

Comment: for `console.log(response.GetUserDetailsResult);` getting `{\"Table\":[{\"UserName\":\"E0205\",\"EmpName\":\"Manjeet\",\"LocationName\":\"Gurgaon\",\"Designation\":\"Analyst\"}]}`

Comment: Cool...now you have your data.......just use dot(.) operator to get it......try `console.log(response.GetUserDetailsResult.Table[0].UserName);` to get the username...since table is an array.

Comment: its throwing **Uncaught TypeError:** Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: try `console.log(response.GetUserDetailsResult.Table);`

Comment: then you probably did something wrong somewhere.....cause I replicated the same thing and getting the answer......debug the solution

Comment: I had used dataset `ds = dal.GetDataSet("dbConn", "GetUserDetailsSP", sqlparams); string jsonValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);` to get **json** data. How can change that in array. may be, thats why i cant extract data in json data.

Comment: if you think that is the problem, change it into an custom object and see it solves your problem